# Fill color on an empty space on a sprite

Tags: unity, sprites, color

I'm trying to make a coloring game, of which I already have a drawing (outline) of an object - let's say a face of a dog. How can I do it that whenever I click for example the eyes, it will "fill" any empty space inside the eye part of the image to a specific color?

The other solution I have of this is to manually export each "spaces" I want the player to color [ex: eyes, mouth, nose, and empty face]. And then I would just assemble back these images to their correct placements to give an illusion that's just one whole image of a dog's face. The player can now click the nose, and the nose's color would then change.

This is nice for simple images with 4-5 parts. But for example abstract looking drawings where it has like 70-100 spaces, exporting them and then assembling them 1 by 1 would be such a tedious task. Is there any way I could just import the outline drawing in Unity, and let Unity automatically detects these spaces for me?

Comment: Maybe a flood fill would help you in case you don't want to seperate it fully into small pieces

Comment: @Zibelas Yes exactly! Something like a flood fill would be a great solution. However though I don't anything about it in Unity. Could you give some ideas on how to do a flood fill in Unity?

Comment: Have you tried to search youtube or similar for a basic tutorial on it and you are struggling with a specific part of implementing it? In that case please post your code, what is not working and any error, if you have some.

Comment: There's nothing special about Unity that changes how you would implement a standard algorithm like a flood fill. You write the algorithm in your own code, following existing tutorials that explain how, then write the results into your texture using `Texture.SetPixels()` or `SetPixels32()`, which [you can find explained in the Unity API documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture2D.SetPixels32.html), then call [Apply()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture2D.Apply.html) to send the updated version to the GPU.